# C++17: How to get the index of a work item in parallel STL

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Is there a way to know an ID/index of a work item in parallel algorithms?

That would be useful for example in generating iota:

```
std::vector<int> vec(max_size);
std::for_each(std::execution::par, vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
   [](int& elem) {
    elem = work_item_index;
});
```

but how to compute that `work_item_index` value efficiently?

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, there's no explicit API to fetch that work item index, so I'm just wondering what's the most efficient way to generate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: This approach is not guaranteed to work, as the element identity (i.e. the address) cannot be relied upon in parallel execution.

A correct solution is to tie the iterator range with a range of indices, as shown in Caleth's answer.

<strike>You can use pointer arithmetic:</strike>

```
int* beg = vec.data();
std::for_each(std::execution::par, vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
   [beg](int& elem) {
    elem = &elem - beg;
});
```

Obviously, this only works for containers which store the elements contiguously.

Comment: nice! so that could be a manual version of parallel iota for `std::vector`

Comment: but according to the spec:
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/algorithms.parallel#defns
"This implies that user-supplied function objects should not rely on object identity of arguments for such input sequences" (because those elements might be copied)

Comment: @fen Damn it. You're right. I don't think my answer is correct then. You'll need to zip with iota like the other answer suggests.

Comment: so it's implementation dependent, it seems to work fine on MSVC, but it's not a general and proper approach

Comment: another correction :) for_each cannot copy elements so that "trick" is safe, but it's unsafe for other algorithms like transform: "Unlike the rest of the algorithms, for_each is not allowed to make copies of the elements in the sequence even if they are trivially copyable. " - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

Answer (score 3):

You operate on a range that includes an index.

```
std::vector<int> vec(max_size);
auto indexed_vec = ranges::view::zip(vec, ranges::view::indices(vec));
std::for_each(std::execution::par, indexed_vec.begin(), indexed_vec.end(), 
   [](std::tuple<int&, int> elem) {
    std::get<0>(elem) = std::get<1>(elem);
});
```

Comment: is there a solution that doesn't require ranges?

Comment: @fen well, there are other [range-like libraries](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/combine.html), or you can write the machinery yourself

Comment: I can't seem to find `view::indexes`, is that the correct view?

Comment: @user975989 oops, it's `view::indices`

Comment: That also doesn't work, `indices` takes an `Integral`, although I wish it took a range.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's not standardized. It depends on parallel engine that is used for algorithms' parallelization.
For example, `omp_get_thread_num()` for OpenMP.

However, if you just want to get index of current processing element of vector you can use `counting_iterator`.
As soon as it's also non-standardized feature, you can use it from libraries: [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html), [TBB](https://github.com/01org/tbb/blob/tbb_2019/include/tbb/iterators.h), [Intel's Parallel STL](https://github.com/intel/parallelstl/blob/master/include/pstl/iterators.h)

```
std::vector<int> vec(max_size);
auto first = vec.begin();
std::for_each(std::execution::par, counting_iterator<int>(0), counting_iterator<int>(max_size), 
   [first](int& work_item_index) {
    first[work_item_index] = work_item_index;
});
```